# why url_for don't work but I can find the endpoint in url_map

Tags: python, flask

I write a plugin as follow:

```
def init_app(self, app, blueprint):
    self.app = app
    @blueprint.route('/static/'+JSGLUE_JS_NAME, methods=['GET'])
    def serve_js():
        return make_response(
                (self.generate_js(), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'})
        )
```

however url_for cannot work,saying 
`BuildError: ('main.serve_js', {}, None)`

when I run "python manage.py shell",I found after creating the app, the endpoint is in the app.url_map while I did not find it when create at my script.

Comment: When I remove `/static` from route，it works!why?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably not name the [Blueprint](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/) `blueprint` but something else.

Did you register the blueprint?

Then when defining the route I would do

```
@something.route('/static/<JSGLUE_JS_NAME>', methods=['GET'])
```

Then the call for the route with `url_for` will have probably the pattern:

```
url_for('something.static', filename='mysuperfile.js')
```

But it's hard to help without a bit more details